# Access mysql database with PHP and Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

My code is ctrl C ctrl V from this tutorial.

Changes: URL changed in code to: `"http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/name_php.php"`

Problem (after trying see products from Android):

```
07-17 17:39:13.168: E/JSON Parser(898): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-17 17:39:13.168: W/dalvikvm(898): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-17 17:39:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 4 more
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898): Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40529288 that was originally added here
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40529288 that was originally added here
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-17 17:39:13.908: E/WindowManager(898):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i think the first line says it all

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as the first line of the dump says:

```
Value <br of type java.lang.String
      ^^^--- here
```

You're trying to parse what looks to be HTML, not JSON.

Comment: Where do I find the error? All the code: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ the PHP seems correct. The code stop inside JSONParser class, because I don't receive the logcat in doInBackground with "All Products" tag.

Comment: this has nothing to do the code causing this error, technically. it's wherever you're getting this string from that's the problem. wherever it's coming from is NOT giving you a json string. it's giving you html. but since your code just blindly assumes you could never get anything BUT json from this resource, you don't handle the cases when something bad comes in. It's as if a drugstore sent you a chainsaw instead of your headache pills, and you're wondering why it's so hard to swallow the chainsaw.